# Extending the Company pages on Careers to include reviews

Tags: feature-request, jobs

This might be a point of debate, but has any thought been given to expanding Careers with a system to leave anonymous reviews of companies you've worked for?

Glassdoor already provides this functionality, but as a developer, I find that the information there is heavily skewed by non-tech employees. It also doesn't give me much insight into the company's development process, the languages and technologies it uses, or the general environment on the development side.

Basically, I'd like to have insight into prospective employers from other developers who have worked there.

I think there's definitely an unfilled niche here.

Comment: Problem is moderating the feedback and making sure it's legit, e.g. rival company can leave false feedback just to harm their competitors.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be much of an issue, as Careers is invite only and the users are generally professional. I think if this were a serious concern, it would already be a big issue on Glassdoor.

Comment: I'd actually really like to see this; I've had this exact scenario in the past.